# Unable to parse the telerik grid used in view page for Itextsharp pdf conversion

Tags: c#, itext, telerik-grid

Using the itextsharp dll for the pdf conversion, need to parse the htmlString which is the return of view page has telerik grid, even after stripping the javascripts in the htmlstring, due to telerik grid elements its having few javascripts for conversion.

Below is the html tag i got as result view page.

> type="text/javascript">
>
> ```
>                                         <li><a class="top" href='/User/UserProfile'>
>                                             <img style="padding-right: 5px;" src='/Images/profile.gif'>Profile</a></li>
>                                         <li><a class="bottom" href='/Home/GeneralSetting'>
>                                             <img style="padding-right: 5px;"
> ```
>
> src='/Images/settings.gif'>Settings
>
> type='text/css' />";
>                var css10 = "";
>                var css11 = "";
>                if ( printDiv == "maincontent-details" )             {
>                    gridTitle = "Role Management";
>                    substring = roleManagement_CSS( substring );             }
>                if ( document.getElementById( "RolesList" ) != null )             {
>                    document.getElementById( "RolesList" ).setAttribute( "style",
>   "page-break-after:auto;page-break-before:auto;page-break-inside:avoid;list-style:none;"
>   );
>                }
>                if (document.getElementById("gridOrgStatusList") != null || document.getElementById("gridOrgLevelTypeList") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("BusinessProfileList") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("TerritoryRule") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("Territories-management-box") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("mainTerritoriesResultArea") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("gridSalesTerritoryAccountRefreshTypeList") !=
>   null || document.getElementById("gridSalesTerrEstCompCountRangeList")
>   != null || document.getElementById("gridTerritoryStatusList") != null
>   || document.getElementById("gridSalesTerritoryTypeList") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("gridQuotaCompValueTypeList") != null ||
>   document.getElementById("gridSalesQuotaDecompositionMethodList") !=
>   null || document.getElementById("gridSalesTBHRejectionList") != null)
>                {
>                    substring = substring.replace( "HEIGHT: 200px", "" );
>                    substring = substring.replace( /class="t-widget t-grid"/g, "class=t-widget t-grid
>   style='overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;'" );
>                    substring = substring.replace( "PADDING-RIGHT: 17px", "line-height:0px;" );
>                    substring = substring.replace( "WIDTH:

Comment: can strip the javascripts with regex?

Comment: i have mentioned already for few javascripts able to manage not stripping the telerik things..

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: i can not get proper html.scroll between code and some tag is missing.

Comment: If the Telerik grid control renders JavaScript which in turn renders HTML then this won't work. iTextSharp's parser needs raw HTML and optionally CSS.

Comment: can i have anyother open source for pdf generation other than pdf supports for the html pages with scripts and styles?